# Loading textures with JSONloader

Tags: json, three.js, textures

I'm a newbie, and I think I missed something.
Could someone check, please?
HTML page: http://xalien95.altervista.org/pkmnxy_engine/alisopoli.html
MODEL and TEXTURES: http://xalien95.altervista.org/pkmnxy_engine/alisopoli/
I can see the model (with weird colors), but not the textures (it's a mesh with multiple materials).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I tried with all the materials types:

- THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
- THREE.MeshDepthMaterial
- THREE.MeshLambertMaterial
- THREE.MeshNormalMaterial
- THREE.MeshPhongMaterial

But noone works, so I think I've missed something (or the materials path is different).
Here's the script:

```
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, loader;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

            loader.load( "./alisopoli/alisopoli.js", function( geometry, materials ) {
                var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( materials );
                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, faceMaterial );
                mesh.scale.set( 100, 100, 100 );
                mesh.position.y = -150;
                mesh.position.x = 0;
                mesh.rotation.x = 60;
                scene.add( mesh );
            } );


            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            //var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
            //directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
            //scene.add(directionalLight);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            //mesh.rotation.y += 0.005;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );` Also, the exporter seems to have assigned a `lightMap` to each material. Set those to `null`. If you still have problems, start with a simpler project until you get it working. Try to ask questions that will be helpful to others.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you! It works!
Now I'm having problems with THREE.DoubleSide and the alpha channel of the textures. I tried to add 
`faceMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;`
but it doesn't work.

Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

The weird colors are because you are assigning every mesh a "MeshNormalMaterial" during your load. You should check  the three.js json loader examples or somehow get the correct material instead of assignen MeshNormalMaterials to the sub-meshes

Comment: I don't know exatcly how to proceed; I tried searching in other examples and I got this `var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '1.png' ), ambient: 0x999999, color: 0xffffff, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 25, morphTargets: true } );`.
How could I do?
Thank you for the quick reply